# What causes this compiler discrepancy whilst using function-like macros containing colons?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, precompile

The `A()` macro will only expand on MSVC, but not GCC/Clang unless `A()` is placed with a prefix e.g. `Test A()`.

By running the following snippet under the `-E` (`/E`) flag ([godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/VoCJFg)):

```c
#define A() HelloWorld::
#define B() ::

A()
B()
```

We see MSVC gives the following output:

```cpp
HelloWorld::
::
```

And GCC/Clang gives a different output:

```cpp
::
```

But then running this snippet:

```cpp
#define A() HelloWorld::

A()
Test A()
```

Gives us the following on all 3 compilers:

```cpp
HelloWorld::
Test HelloWorld::
```

Why is the GCC/Clang output missing the first line?
Why does it expand all occurrences correctly when `Test A()` is written?
Is this well defined within the standard, or is this compiler-specific?

Comment: Can't you find a way to replace the macro with a proper function? Macros are *evil*.

Comment: I'm with Jesper.  What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?  Chances are there's A Better Way.

Comment: No problem to solve, I was just messing around with the godbolt site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an artifact of how Compiler Explorer (godbolt.org) presents the output by default. Disable the `.LX0` option in the output pane and it will present the output that you expect.

Compiler Explorer assumes that the output is assembly and treats `HelloWorld::` as an unused label that is removed by the `.LX0` option.

In your second example `HelloWorld::` is not removed, because it appears later in the output making it seem as if the "label" is used and since `.LX0` filters only labels that are unused, it will not remove it.

It doesn't happen with MSVC, because MSVC's `/E` output is not presented in the assembly pane.

In general if you want to see the full unfiltered compiler output uncheck all the boxes in the assembly pane. (I don't know whether there is any other processing happening that can't be disabled.)

See also [this Compiler Explorer issue](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/1380) relating to presentation problems with the `-E` option.

Comment: So why isn't it consistently removing it in all the output?

Comment: @MarkStorer With OP's second example it seems as if the `HelloWorld` "label" is reused later, so `.LX0` doesn't remove it.

Comment: @YorekB Then you should probably upvote/accept his answer.  You're new, no problem.  When someone helps you out, you show how helpful they were by upvoting and accepting (clicking on the hollow checkmark will turn it green IIRC when you're the one asking the question).